# iOS app not responding while UI recording

Tags: ios, user-interface, testing, ios9, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to record an UI test for my iPad app. When I press tab bar item to navigate to the other screen recording capture my action correctly but my app does not responding at all. Afterwards, when I run my test it actually navigates to the proper screen.

Any idea what can cause that behavior?

Thanks.

```
- (void)testAddActivity {
    XCUIElementQuery *tabBar = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init].tabBars;
    XCUIElement *activitiesButton = tabBar.buttons[@"Activities"];
    [activitiesButton tap]; //App does not responding in recording
}
```